# How to write useMutation hook with onCompleted as a parameter?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I need to write dedicated hook useMutation with onCompleted and parameter onMutationCompleted.

In file it uses like:

```
const [data] = useClearWorkerMutation({ onCompleted: onMutationCompleted });
```

I don't know how to put `onCompleted` in this hook correctly.

```
export function useClearWorkerMutation() {
  return useMutation<ClearWorkerMutationData, ClearWorkerMutationInput>(
    CLEAR_WORKER_MUTATION,
    {
      onCompleted: (data) =>
      },
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks#function-signature-2) the function signature for `useMutation` is:

```
function useMutation<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables>(
  mutation: DocumentNode,
  options?: MutationHookOptions<TData, TVariables>,
): MutationTuple<TData, TVariables> {}
```

If the only option is `onCompleted` and you have some query then you would have:

```
useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION,{onCompleted: (data) => {…your function…})
```

It looks as if you're doing this correctly. Are you getting errors? Is your `onCompleted` function not getting executed?  What's not working?